# Changing IDLE version from python 2.7 to 3.4

Tags: windows, python-idle, python-3.4

I have installed **Python v3.4** and that added **Python27** and **Python34** in my C:\ Thus both have their own **idle.pyw's** but the problem is that they point to the same Python27 version. How do I use **Python 3.4** through the **idle** then? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you see the idle.bat in your Python directory? Use idle.bat instead of idle.pyw, and then it will work well. Check what's inside of the file:

```
@echo off
rem Start IDLE using the appropriate Python interpreter
set CURRDIR=%~dp0
start "IDLE" "%CURRDIR%..\..\pythonw.exe" "%CURRDIR%idle.pyw" %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
```

Comment: I reinstalled ActivePython-3.4.1.0-win64-x64.msi. Now I have only one directory Python34 in my C:\ but new problem - IDLE won't open. Also, the idle.bat file has all the stuff you have written above. @yushulx

Comment: You don't need to reinstall Python. Just run the different idle.bat which is located at Python3.4 or Python2.7 directory. That's enough. It will run the appropriate Python interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

idle.pyw does not 'point' anywhere.  It is identical, I believe, in 2.7 and 3.4.  If you start it with python x.y, it will start up Idle x.y.  So you have to start the version of python that you want.

If you install 3.4 with the python.org .msi file, the py launcher is installed.  (I do not know what ActiveState's installer does.)  From the command line, py -x.y starts python x.y if installed.  py -x starts the most recent version of x.y.

```
py -x -m idlelib
```

will start Idle.

The Start Menu Idle icons, which I keep pinned to my Win7 taskbar, start Idle with the corresponding python.

I have no idea why reinstalling ASPyhton deleted the 2.7 install or how it messed up anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Things didn't work, I had to reinstall Activestate python 2.7 and settle with it. Also, installed the Komodo IDE without worrying about IDLE.